Can I have multiple root bones or pivots for my sword rig? One that move with each other but doesn't cause any problem
Let's focus on the grip and let's call the bones from top-down as: b1 (Pommel) to b5 (End of the grip).
I have a big sword with a long grip and a ring pommel I want to use as a rotational pivot (b1 / thus the root bone). However, whenever the character holds the sword on the other end of the long grip (b4-b5 or any), rotating and moving the sword becomes clunky and unintuitive. The root is way too far to adjust manually while using the cursor pivot is too slow and unreliable.
I'm looking for a way to move or add multiple pivot points wherever my character's hand will parent themselves to. So if the characters parent themselves on b3. I can both move and rotate on b3 pivot perfectly without breaking anything.
Any tips? Thank you in advance


Check this old but very good rigging tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Po1mBseLJsw
